# How do I send notification at random time?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

Already I read some practice and example for my problem but I cannot decide which is good.This reason I ask you which java classes are needed for me?
Some example use AlarmManager and BroadcastReceiver.

MainActivity call setAlarm() which configurate the PendingIntent and send at randomly time a Broadcast and the bcReceiver catch this. That is sounds good, but  I can't implemet. I need a example, what is working on android 4 or over.

When the user click the notification, it call a fragment.

I read the android doc but I find several example, and I don't know which is right.

Please, anybody have an example for me, don't keep in yourself and show me the light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `Service` or `IntentService` class. Even if the application is paused you will be able to send notification or whatever.

Create a class that extends `Service` or `IntentService`. Do not forget to put it on the manifest file.

Here is the best example of how to implement it :
https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html